# gyp ERR! configure error in ubuntu while installing angular 4 project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, node-gyp

I am a new bee in `angular4`. I am setting up an `angular4` project (it's a simple admin panel) using `npm install`, but it's showing

> gyp ERR! configure error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied,

[image]

It is happening to any `angular4` projects, but simple `angular4` program is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project directory. and if you use mac than run below command, or for windows run the following without sudo,

1. sudo npm uninstall
2. sudo npm clean cache
3. sudo npm install
4. sudo npm install @angular/cli